# Get list of files loaded to Snowflake Internal Staging via PUT command

Tags: python-3.x, copy, cloud, put, snowflake-task

I am moving files from local to Snowflake Internal Staging using PUT command in Python
**put file:///Path/file_name***

I want to get list of all the files which were moved by this command. I tried using Query id, but when I go to snowflake History and click on query ID for put I see below in query result:
"The Result for this query have expired"

I was hoping to find list of files moved in query result. I see relevant information for Copy and other insert command but not for put.

How can I find this list?

Comment: Are you trying to tie specific files to specific queries?  Or are you just interested in what files are currently on stage?  You could run a `LIST` command against the stage to see the files that have been moved there.

Comment: I need file loaded as part of that specific query. List will give me incorrect results if some other process also loads files at the same time.